# Xamarin TextCell on UWP moves when tapped

Tags: xamarin.forms, tableview

In my Xamarin Forms app, I have numerous TextCells displayed in a TableView.

When run the app on UWP, I see that the text moves slightly (slightly indented) when the cell is tapped on. I suspect this is done as a form of highlighting the cell when it is tapped.

I find this very distracting and is different from what happens on iOS or Android.
Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: you would need to create a custom visual state manager for pressed state in native UWP App.xaml and then create a custom renderer to use that.

This is for listview it'll give you an idea https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e5dc0add-5176-4891-93d0-46c500cced4d/uwp-how-to-remove-tap-animation-when-a-listview-item-is-clicked?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It looks like a messy solution, but maybe that's all there is.  Why would I need a custom renderer here?  Seems like I just put the modified xaml in the App.xaml for the Windows project.

Comment: UWP is messy, and how would you consume that modified template in your shared Xamarin control. You create a custom renderer , consume it in Native and then use that custom control in shared proj